# Calculating coefficient of restitution for a three-body system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, collision

I have been asked the following question:

> Two billiard balls of the same size and mass are in contact on a billiard table. A third ball of the same mass and size strikes them symmetrically and remains at rest after the impact. Find the coefficient of restitution between the balls?

Given that  I figure out the velocity of separation for the two billiard balls that were in touch, should I be considering the $v_\textrm{sep}$ for only one of the two balls (while it is clear that $v_\textrm{app}$ will be the same for both balls) when calculating the coefficient of restitution ($e$)?

If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CoR is *assumed* to be the same for both impacts.

The entire forward momentum of the 3rd ball is transferred to the two balls equally, so each has exactly 1/2 of the momentum in the direction of motion of the 3rd ball.

From the contact geometry (I think contact normal is 30° from the symmetry plane) you work out the momentum perpendicular to the symmetry plane. This relationship is going to give you the CoR.